# Log Forging issue on long data type in Checkmarx scan

Tags: java, spring, logging, log-forging

In checkmarx scan I got log forging issue when I log Id with getter method which is of long type. Can a long data type cause log forging if Yes how can we overcome this.

I'm not sure about long data type. Please explain this in detail.